# What is meant by derating in this context?

Tags: temperature, motor-controller

At page 33 of [this](http://www.ni.com/pdf/manuals/AKD_Install.pdf) motor driver there is a section includes the term **derating** due to temperature:

[image]

What is meant by *continuous current derating 4% per Kelvin* in this context? Does that mean the motor current will decrease with the temperature?

Comment: The user should take care to use only 96 % of the rated current of the motor driver at a temperature of 41 °C. 60 % at 50 °C and only 40 % at 55 °C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The maximum current rating of the drive is (say) 12A RMS on the nameplate.

The drive can operate within that limit over the range 0 to 40°C.

If you must operate at a temperature higher than 40°C you must derate the nameplate rating by 4% per K, up to a maximum of 55°C (15K difference) at which temperature the drive is only capable of 40% of the nameplate rating (100% - (4% * 15K)), or 4.8A RMS in my example.

The drive should not be operated at all below 0°C or above 55°C.

Comment: you mean max 56C? is that K a typo?

Comment: @user1999 Yes, fixed, thanks.

Comment: But the device should be operated in not more than 55 °C.

Comment: Would a  thermal relay which be set to 55C be adequate for precaution ?

Comment: The device may already have internal protection that will shut it down, but perhaps not exactly at 55°C.

Answer (score 2):

No.  It will not decrease the motor current.  The motor current will continue to be the same.  However - and this is the problem - the amount of current that the chip can safely provide is less at higher temperatures.  If you exceed the current the device can safely provide the chip may be destroyed.  As the motor current will not decrease, you need to make sure that the current drawn from the chip by the motor does not exceed the current that the chip can safely provide over the operating temperature range.

Answer (score 1):

> Does that mean the motor current will decrease with the temperature?

No. If it is anticipated that the temperature will exceed 40°C, a motor driver with a higher current rating should be selected.

The only way the motor current can decrease is by reducing the torque demand on the motor. It may be possible to do that by some adjustment of the driven machine. For example the torque demand of a metal-cutting machine can be reduced by reducing the rate at which the cutting tool is advanced.

The torque demand of a fan or centrifugal pump can be reduced by reducing the operating speed. Motor drivers can usually be programmed to limit the current, but it would be unusual for that to be done in response to temperature increase. Automatic current limiting would simply reduce the speed of a fan or centrifugal pump, but the speed might be rapidly reduced to zero with other types of loads.

The section of the manual shown in the question includes "**NOTICE** The drive shuts down...in case of excessively high temperature in the control cabinet." That tells you that the controller does nothing to decrease the motor current when the temperature limit is exceeded. The motor is simply shut off in that case.

Answer (score 0):

> Does that mean the motor current will decrease with the temperature?

Yes, it does mean exactly that. The power dissipation is increasing the devices temperature and has to be radiated to the environment. When the chip becomes to hot it will reduce/derate the output current to decrease the thermal stress.

So at 55°C the output current will be lowered by 15K x 4%/K = 60%.

Comment: You mean the current to the motor will reduce 60% means the torque will also reduced ? And is this derating done by internal circuitry?

Comment: I would think it means that the USER should cut the current

Comment: Yes, the current to the motor is reduced. This also reduces the torque.
Why do you think you will exceed this temperature?

Comment: @jusaca because it will be in an enclosure and indoors environment which can go up to 40C . I have seen VFD ambient in an enclosure  ambient was approaching ton 50C  for instance so a fan was installed.

Comment: Scott Seidman, are you sure about that?
I would have assumed the termperature control of the motor control to do this automatically. But I can not find more details in the datasheet.

Comment: It's the assumption I would go with, and most closely matches my experience with the term "derating".  I have no idea if the motor controller even measures ambient temperature

Comment: @jusaca At the bottom of the controller information posted in the question, it says the controller will shut the motor off if excess temperature is detected. That is a pretty strong indication that the controller does not reduce the motor current.